# Symfony 2 Attempted to load class "IoServer" from namespace "Ratchet\Server"

Tags: php, symfony

I have this command:

```
    class SockServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand implements MessageComponentInterface
    {

//... methods for implementing MessageComponentInterface here

/**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        protected function configure()
        {
            $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;

            $this
                ->setName('game_main:sock_server_command')
                ->setDescription('Hello PhpStorm');
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
            // $port = $input->getArgument('port');

            $server = \Ratchet\Server\IoServer::factory(
                new \Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
                    new \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                        $this
                    )
                ),
                7000
            );

            $server->run();
        }
    }
```

if I run command `app/console game_main:sock_server_command`, which gives me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Ratchet\Server\IoServer' not found in /var/public_html/symfony.loc/www/src/Game/MainBundle/Command/SockServerCommand.php on line 69
[2015-07-03 17:58:01] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Class 'Ratchet\Server\IoServer' not found {"type":1,"file":"/var/public_html/symfony.loc/www/src/Game/MainBundle/Command/SockServerCommand.php","line":69,"level":-1,"stack":[]} 



[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]           
Attempted to load class "IoServer" from namespace "Ratchet\Server".  
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?              

game_main:sock_server_command
```

Why is Symfony not able to find this class? What is the solution?

Comment: Does the class exists? In which file does it live? How did you install the library?

Comment: The class does exists. 
I'm did composer require guzzle/guzzle && composer require cboden/ratchet.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I am going to use port 8080:
1. First create a bundle for managing socket connections: App\SocketBundle

2. Create a handler (service) located at: App\SocketBundle\Handler

```
<?php

namespace App\SocketBundle\Handler;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class MainSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface
{

  protected $clients;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage();
  }

  public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
  {
    // Store the new connection to send messages to later
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
  }

  public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
  {
    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        if ($from === $client) {
            $client->send("OK");
        }
    }
  }

  public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
  {
    // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
    $this->clients->detach($conn);

    echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
  }

  public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
  {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

    $conn->close();
  }
}
```

3. Register the service at App/SocketBundle/Resources/config/services.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>

   <container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

   <parameters>
     <parameter key="main.socket.service.class">App\SocketBundle\Handler\MainSocketHandler</parameter>
   </parameters>

   <services>
     <service id="main.socket.service" class="%main.socket.service.class%">
     </service>
   </services>

   </container>
   ```

4. Don't forget to load the new resource file at app/config.yml

```
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }
  - { resource: security.yml }
  - { resource: "@AppSocketBundle/Resources/config/services.xml" }
```

5. Create a symfony command at App/SocketBundle/Command

```
<?php

namespace Lima3\SocketBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;

class RunSocketCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
  protected $route;

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->route = 'cd ' . __DIR__ . '/../../../../;php app/console ';
  }

  protected function configure()
  {
    $this
        ->setName('run:socket')
        ->setDescription('Run Socket');
  }

  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
  {
    $mainSocket = $this->getContainer()->get('main.socket.service');

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        $mainSocket,
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
  }
}
```

6. Finally, run the command:

```
    php app/console run:socket
```